# C# Do not split string on comma

Tags: c#, csv

I am using Xamarin.Forms to create a data collection application. One particular feature of this app is to export the data via csv. When captured the data is written to a text file using the following method:

```
 public void WriteToFile(string CompanyName, string Website, string FirsttName, string LastName, string JobTitle, string Phone, string Email, string Solution, string Notes, string ContactOwner, string EventName)
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string filename = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "Prospects.txt");
        string lineToBeAdded = string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},{8},{9},{10}", CompanyName, Website, FirsttName, LastName, JobTitle, Phone, Email, Solution, Notes, ContactOwner, EventName);
        File.AppendAllText(filename, lineToBeAdded + Environment.NewLine);


    }
```

My problem is that in the variable NOTES the user uses commas in their description which messes up the structure of the csv.

How do I force ignore commas in this string?

Comment: Typically you would enclose that field with double quotes. It's going to depend on whether your consumer respects that convention. Of course, you now have to accommodate for strings that have double quotes in them as well. It might get extra tricky if the string has something like `\"` in it.

Comment: See [RFC 4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt).

Comment: You would benefit from using a CSV library that can handle the format for you.  CsvHelper comes to mind.

Comment: Use \t separator

Comment: If the columns do not have a string-encapsulation character (typically double quote) as well as an escape character for the string-encapsulation character (typically a second double quote) then you aren't going to have any good way to read this data in. Whoever is producing this CSV needs to try again. A properly formatted line would be;  `1, f2, "this is, a single column of ""data"""`

Comment: You can also replace the comma value of the name with space like `string.Replace(',', ' ');`

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Comment: You can't ignore the commas.  You can either remove them, or "escape" them so that the commas are preserved while still creating "legal" CSV.  Some of the answers below remove the commas, and others escape them.  Your users will probably prefer the commas to be preserved, else why would they have entered them?  But only you can make the final decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Create this function:

```
string GetCsvLine(params string[] fields) =>
   string.Join(",", fields.Select(x => $"\"{x.Replace("\"", "\"\"")}\""));
```

And call it like this, replacing the line in your example code that initializes "lineToBeAdded":

```
string lineToBeAdded = GetCsvLine(CompanyName, Website, FirsttName, LastName, JobTitle, Phone, Email, Solution, Notes, ContactOwner, EventName);
```

### Explanation

Refer [here - RFC4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2) - to the specification for CSV:

Summarizing:

- A field must be enclosed in double-quotes, if it contains a comma, a line break, or a double-quote.
- Any double-quotes **within** a field must themselves be doubled.
- *Bonus: using 'params' and LINQ allows you to call this method with a variable number of arguments, eliminating the need for a format string with the exact number of placeholders.*

Answer (score 3):

To escape comma warp each column in double quotes, to scape double qoutes use 2 double qoutes instead of each:

```
 string lineToBeAdded = string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\",\"{3}\",\"{4}\",\"{5}\",\"{6}\",\"{7}\",\"{8}\",\"{9}\",\"{10}\"", 
CompanyName.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 Website.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 FirsttName.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 LastName.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 JobTitle.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 Phone.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 Email.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 Solution.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 Notes.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 ContactOwner.Replace("\"","\"\""),
 EventName.Replace("\"","\"\""));
```

Comment: What if one of the variable values contains a quotation mark?

Comment: @Chris, this answer handles that scenario properly, by doubling any contained quotation marks, and then enclosing each field in quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

Also you don't have to use comma's, you can use a | or something else the user doesn't use.

To make it even more friendly you can specify the delimiter in the first line, excel supports that I know.

```
sep=|
header1|header2|header3
1,2|2,3|3,4
```